# Pandas pd.to_datetime returning 'NaT' when format is valid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am unable to convert a Column from a DataFrame (temp_series) containing date and time information to datetime object. When usind `pd.to_datetime()` I only get 'NaT' values.

Here is my DataFrame:

```
    Timestamp[ms]   D0_Tc0
1   11/05/2022 07:33:57:851 PM  25
2   11/05/2022 07:33:57:967 PM  25
3   11/05/2022 07:33:58:083 PM  25
4   11/05/2022 07:33:58:184 PM  25
5   11/05/2022 07:33:58:299 PM  25
```

```
temp_series.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3248 entries, 1 to 3248
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column                        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                        --------------  ----- 
 0     Timestamp[ms]               3248 non-null   object
 1    D0_Tc 0                      3248 non-null   object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 76.1+ KB
```

I've tried this so far:

```
pd.to_datetime(temp_series['Timestamp[ms]'], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S:%f %p", errors='coerce')
```

But this returns 'NaT' values:

```
1      NaT
2      NaT
3      NaT
4      NaT
5      NaT
        ..
3244   NaT
3245   NaT
3246   NaT
3247   NaT
3248   NaT
Name: Timestamp[ms], Length: 3248, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Why is `pd.to_datetime()` unable to convert the 'Timestamp[ms]' column into datetime object?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the output of `temp_series.loc[:5, 'Timestamp[ms]'].tolist()`?

Comment: What happens if you do not set a `format`, just `pd.to_datetime(temp_series['Timestamp[ms]'])`? Letting pandas infer the format sometimes prevents errors that are caused by parsing directives, such as `%p` which do not work on all systems.

Comment: @mozway the output of ```temp_series.loc[:5, 'Timestamp[ms]'].tolist()``` hinted that there was a white space at the end of each date, so changing format to ```format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S:%f %p "``` solved this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @JotaN92 that why I ask the list output, which is otherwise unseen as a print, glad you solved it ;)

Answer (score 1):

There must be something incorrect with your data as I cannot reproduce your issue:

```
temp_series = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp[ms]': ['11/05/2022 07:33:57:851 PM', '11/05/2022 07:33:57:967 PM', '11/05/2022 07:33:58:083 PM', '11/05/2022 07:33:58:184 PM', '11/05/2022 07:33:58:299 PM'], 'D0_Tc0': [25, 25, 25, 25, 25]})

pd.to_datetime(temp_series['Timestamp[ms]'], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S:%f %p", errors='coerce')
```

Output:

```
1   2022-11-05 19:33:57.851
2   2022-11-05 19:33:57.967
3   2022-11-05 19:33:58.083
4   2022-11-05 19:33:58.184
5   2022-11-05 19:33:58.299
Name: Timestamp[ms], dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Ensure that there are no extra characters in the strings. Maybe try to run the conversion without `errors='coerce'` on only the first few rows to see if you have an error.